# How Do I Send Modified And Added Rows Between Two Servers That Implement The Same Database?

Tags: sql, vb.net

What I Want To Do :

i have a database with tables :

```
Items
ItemsBarcodes
Invoices
InvoiceDetails
```

the same database exists on server A and server B

only applications working on server A are allowed to add/modify rows to items and itemsBarcodes tables

i need a way to programatically send a file from application working on sever A that contains the added/modified data to the application that works on server B so that it can update the items and itemsBarcodes datatables

How I am Currently Doing It

1-i export the data from server A to Files like this :

```
Try
    strm = Nothing

    strm = New FileStream(ItemsFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    srItems.Serialize(strm, ds.Items)
    strm.Close()
    strm = Nothing

    strm = New FileStream(ItemsACFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    srItemsAc.Serialize(strm, ds.ItemsAC)
    strm.Close()
    strm = Nothing

    strm = New FileStream(ItemsTagFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    srItemsTag.Serialize(strm, ds.ItemsTag)
    strm.Close()
    strm = Nothing

    strm = New FileStream(BarcodesFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    srBarcodes.Serialize(strm, ds.Barcodes)
    strm.Close()
    frmBase.ntfy.ShowBalloonTip(5000, "Done", "Items Count = " & ds.Items.Count, ToolTipIcon.Info)
Catch ex As Exception
    frmBase.ntfy.ShowBalloonTip(5000, "Error", ex.Message, ToolTipIcon.Error)
End Try
```

2-the i try to load the data back at server B like this :

```
Dim ds2 As New UltimatePharmaDataSet
Try
    strm = Nothing
    strm = New FileStream(ItemsFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    source = "Items"
    ds2.ReadXml(strm)
    strm.Close()


    strm = Nothing
    strm = New FileStream(ItemsACFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    source = "ItemsAC"
    ds2.ReadXml(strm)
    strm.Close()


    strm = Nothing
    strm = New FileStream(ItemsTagFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    source = "ItemsTag"
    ds2.ReadXml(strm)
    strm.Close()


    strm = Nothing
    strm = New FileStream(BarcodesFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    source = "Barcodes"
    ds2.ReadXml(strm)
    strm.Close()
    source = ""

    For Each r As UltimatePharmaDataSet.ItemsRow In ds2.Items
        source = "Items" & r.ItemName
        If ds.Items.FindByItemID(r.ItemID) Is Nothing Then

            r.SetAdded()
        Else

            r.SetModified()


        End If
        r.EndEdit()
    Next

    For Each r As UltimatePharmaDataSet.BarcodesRow In ds2.Barcodes
        source = "Barcodes" & r.ItemsRow.ItemName & " " & r.Barcode
        If ds.Barcodes.FindByItemIDBarcode(r.ItemID, r.Barcode) Is Nothing Then

            r.SetAdded()
        End If
        r.EndEdit()
    Next
    source = ""
    tadMngr.UpdateAll(ds2)
    frmBase.ntfy.ShowBalloonTip(5000, "Done", "Items Count = " & ds2.Items.Count, ToolTipIcon.Info)
Catch ex As Exception
    frmBase.ntfy.ShowBalloonTip(5000, "Error", ex.Message & source, ToolTipIcon.Error)
Finally
    strm.Close()
End Try
```

where ds represents the original dataset on server B
and ds2 is the dataset read from the files sent from server A

The Problem Is :

when the `tadMngr` ( the TableAdapterManager ) tries to `updateAll(ds2)`
i get the error message :

> "concurrency violation the updateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 record"

i used SQL profiler to find out which rows cause the error
turns out only rows modified in server A or rows that have related rows modified raise this error

the error message is gone after i ignored those rows
but that is not the solution at all

---

can any body help by pointing out what's wrong with my method or point me in the direction of a better method to achieve the same goal ?

thanks every body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [Sql Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx). It does exactly what you need.